# Anyway to link <title> to <div>?

Tags: javascript, html, title

Is there anyway to link the `<title>` to a `<div>` via javascript or php?

I tried

```
document.title.value = document.getElementById("div").innerHTML;
```

but that didn't seem to work

I want to do this because I have multiple pages where I want the `<title>` to the be the same as what is in a `<div>`, but I don't want to handcode it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need `document.title.value`, just `document.title` works.

```
document.title=document.getElementById("div").innerHTML;
```

Offcourse, you need to execute this after your DOM loaded. Use the onload in the body or any onload function.

Comment: that was fast, and it worked.   Thanks! 
If you don't mind me asking though, why is "value" not necesary?

Comment: Well because it is the "title" of the document. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.title

Comment: @sukh - `document.title` is the value of the title already. It doesn't have any fields inside of it.

Comment: @sukh "that was fast, and it worked" ... welcome to StackOverflow. That's what we do. Best to catch the board between GMT 00:00 -4 and GMT 00:00 -12 to get the most eyes on it (ok, so I'm culturally biased but it seems to be true given the site is mostly English speaking), but post 24/7 for speedy results. Also visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for a few pointers. Enjoy the site!

Comment: @sukh Also, if you found the answer to be most helpful, click the checkmark under the votes to the left of the answer. That tells everyone else you've found the answer you were looking for and awards both you and the poster a bit of reputation.

Comment: this is my first time visiting. i clicked the checkmark under the first answer. 
thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `.value` on the `document.title`. I would also use `.innerText` instead of `.innerHtml`.